# Linear regression why does normal equation give huge error

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am learning ML using [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd6kQQEbq2Q&list=PLE6Wd9FR--EdyJ5lbFl8UuGjecvVw66F6&index=2).

I implemented the code myself by generating a fake data

```
y=2*x1+10*x2+noise+offset
```

Thinking that the normal equation would return theta close to my 'fake slopes'
but as you can see the result is very different(click to view picture): (sorry for no labels, blue is fake data, orange is the predicted data)

[image]

I checked my code, I think there is nothing wrong with the way I implemented it. could someone explain why it does not seem to work?

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


offset = 20

# x1 and x2 are variables, x0 is there so that later when X*thetas, i can have theta1 
x0=np.ones(100)
x1=np.linspace(0,100,100)
x2=np.linspace(0,10,100)

#introduce some noise in the data
fluc=np.random.uniform(-10,10,100)


# you can uncommet the +fluc to add noise
y=2*x1+10*x2+offset#+fluc


# this part is to form the X matrix
x=np.array([x0,x1,x2])
x=np.transpose(x)

# calculating useing normal equation 
x_trans_x=np.matmul(np.transpose(x),x)
part1=np.linalg.inv(x_trans_x)
part2=np.matmul(np.transpose(x),y)
theta=np.matmul(part1,part2)

#use the theta to predict
predicted=theta[0]+theta[1]*x1+theta[2]*x2
print(theta)

#plot
ax.scatter(x1,x2,y)
ax.scatter(x1,x2,predicted)

#show the loss
print(np.sum(np.square(y-predicted)))


plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and update your question so that others can help you. Asking something like - `why it does not seem to work?` is not sufficient. Please provide the error you are facing with its complete trace. Also please provide an expected output.

Comment: What are the actual values for your theta vector?

Comment: theta is [84.22422242  0.         24.        ]
the cost is 147735.8006467683

Comment: I wonder if your design matrix is too near to singular. As it's written x1 ~ 10*x2. That would be consistent with that zero for theta[1]. Try making x2 use a different range than x1

Comment: do you mind explain how that would affect the result?

Comment: When you invert the matrix the inverted matrix is multiplied by 1/det(X). If the matrix is singular the determinate will be zero. In this case you didn't get an error so it might be too close to zero for the computer to maintain accuracy. There are ways around this using matrix decompositions but that is much more complicated

Comment: so the range for x1 is 0-100, the range for x2 is 0-10, are you suggesting that i try a different range for x2 ...say 0-50?

Comment: For testing purposes (I might be totally wrong here!) try something like [-25,25] so there's no linear mapping between the columns.

Comment: yes the determent is very small :2.3196708302794468e-05 for x1(0,100) x2(0,10)

Comment: i tried couple of different ranges for x1 and x2 between -50 to 100. the determent t all seems to be very small around 10^-4 - 10^-5

Comment: i solved it by changing the way i initialize x1 and x2, it used to be x1=np.lispace(a,b,c). now it is x1= np.random(100).